# Подскажите пожалуйста, корректно ли так оформить предложение с такой вот "двойной" прямой речью?

Tags: прямая-речь

> «И как теперь выкинуть эту картину из головы?» — думалось Джею, но из
> уст вырвалось иное, довольно резкое:  — Что смешного?
> — В такое мог поверить только ты.

Не хочется в первом предложении еще раз выделять прямую речь кавычками, дабы не нагромождать, но не уверена, насколько это допустимо.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Дарья, а в каком месте не хочется ставить кавычки – в начале или в конце? И как во всём тексте оформлены диалоги – в кавычках или с абзаца и с тире?

Comment: Я сейчас просмотрела книгу на предмет оформления прямой речи. Вариантов очень много: диалоги, классическая прямая речь внутри абзаца, встроенная речь в кавычках, несобственно-прямая речь и даже просто прямая речь без кавычек в виде отдельных предложений. Динамичность удивительная. Но там определенная художественная задача:  действие романа происходит в течение одного дня, но оно постоянно прерывается  воспоминаниями главного героя о прошлом.

Comment: @Sharon  А как вы нашли книгу? У меня не ищется по этому отрывку...

Comment: https://flibusta.club/b/429871/read   Глава 3, почти начало

Comment: @Sharon  Все глаза сломал, по другим главам прошёлся... А это, оказывается, книга из вашего ответа! Я-то думал, что вы о книге из вопроса. :))

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Здравствуйте. Не хочется ставить кавычки в конце предложения, а диалоги во всем тексте оформлены с нового абзаца и с тире, поэтому и хотелось бы свести кавычки к минимуму, если так можно выразиться)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не рекомендую ориентироваться на "современных писателей". Правила есть. И для нарушения оных надо, во-первых, их знать, во-вторых, чётко понимать, для какой цели нарушаешь.
Ваше оформление правильное. Только фразу "что смешного" напишите с новой строчки.

Comment: Так я же привожу правило Розенталя, а оно не из  "современных". Классика. И автор спрашивает о КАВЫЧКАХ, а не о правильности своего оформления. Правила он, вероятно, знает.

Answer (score 1):

Современные писатели, даже очень известные, не особо утруждают себя оформлением прямой речи по всем правилам, например:

Анна Матвеева. Завидное чувство Веры Стениной (2015).

***Интересно было бы встретиться с этой Тонечкой сейчас**, мрачно думала Стенина, выкапывая из кучи выстиранного, но невыглаженного белья тёплые колготки. **Интересно было бы узнать, сколько желаний сбылось в жизни у этой дуры.***

Здесь прямая речь встроена в авторский текст. Тогда можно предложить такой вариант:

***И как теперь выкинуть эту картину из головы**, думалось Джею, но из уст вырвалось иное, довольно резкое: — Что смешного?*

**ПРАВИЛО** [Розенталь, примечание, пункты 2 и 3](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158#pp158)

Не выделяется кавычками прямая речь в следующих случаях:

2. Если прямая речь приводится в таком виде, который может иметь и косвенная речь с тем же лексическим составом:
   Но мне приходит в голову: точно ли стоит рассказывать мою жизнь? (Т.);

(Это БСП, двоеточие, но можно поставить и запятую, если увеличенной паузы нет.)

3. Если в середину прямой речи вставлен глагол *говорит*, играющий роль вводного слова, указывающего на источник сообщения:

Умру, говорит, и слава Богу, говорит; не желаю, говорит, жить (Т.); Я, говорит, самого вахмистра жандармерии из пистолета убить хочу (Верш.);

Примечание. **[Анна Матвеева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0)**

Это действительно **известный автор**, так что можно предположить, что корректоры и редакторы хорошо поработали над книгой. И это **поиски новых форм,** нормальное явление в литературе.

Comment: Розненталю своё не приписывайте: во 2-м случае он говорит только про двоеточие, в 3-м он говорит только про слово "говорит". Про запятую и "думалось" — ваши домыслы. + предложение вопросительное и вообще заканчивается авторской ремаркой. "Известный автор" — это Агата Кристи. А у вас кто-то, кого без ссылки на вики не опознать. Наши корректоры и редакторы халтурят в каждой книге, и чхали они на качество так же, как издательства на новые формы. Прекращайте их боготоворить. На совесть пашет только "Ладомир" и энтузиасты. А воротилы бизнеса штампуют на скорость. Знаю этот бизнес изнутри.

Comment: Розенталь предлагает варианты оформления дословного высказывания, которые вы понимаете как готовые штампы-стандарты на все времена.  И при этом говорите о  художественной  литературе. Могу предположить, что вы плохо знаете как Розенталя, так и современную литературу. И о стиле комментария. Я не считаю корректным ваше повелительное наклонение: не приписывайте, прекращайте, чхали и прочее. До свидания.

Comment: Розенталь:  Если в области орфографии желательна и необходима полная унификация, то к пунктуации это требование неприменимо. Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии индивидуально-авторского использования знаков препинания, в гибкости пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его оттенки. Все это исключает формальный подход к соблюдению правил .

Comment: А зачем вы сперва прощаетесь, а потом пишите, не поздоровавшись? Вы привели правило, дополнили его отсебятиной, а теперь пытаетесь обосновать свои домыслы общим замечанием Розенталя о том, что правила иногда можно нарушать. На этот форум люди приходят именно с вопросом о том, как можно по стандарту. А в художественной литературе вы хоть всю книгу из вопросительных знаков издайте. Вам нет нужды идти для этого на форум и спрашивать, как правильно, если вы в поиске новых форм.

Comment: До свидания еще раз.  Отсебятина – грубое слово, как и весь ваш недружественный тон.  На этот форум разные люди приходят, уверяю вас. А вы некорректно понимаете Розенталя и его правила, но это ваши проблемы.  А на форуме надо отвечать на вопросы, а не отвечающих  критиковать в таком тоне.  Вся критика – в поле ответа.  "Вам нет нужды идти для этого на форум и спрашивать, как правильно, если вы в поиске новых форм". А это вы кому пишете, тоже мне?  Или всем? Девиз форума лингвистов? Отвечать не надо. Дискуссия закончена.

Comment: Если попрощались, прощайтесь окончательно. Что касается критики ответов, то я за демократию. Пользовательницу по имени Римма вы критиковать не стеснялись, когда она выдала альтернативное мнение вашему. И в этом разговоре именно вы стали комментировать мой ответ. Так что следите за собой, чтобы не приходилось ставить вас на место.