# Нужна ли запятая перед тире: не знаешь, что сказать, — действуй

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

Нужна ли **запятая перед тире** в этих предложениях? Есть ли **правило,** на которое можно дать ссылку?  В литературе встречаются **разные варианты**.

*Не знаешь, **что сказать**(,) – так хоть молчать научись.*  А. Маринина. Ангелы на льду не выживают. Т. 1 (2014)

*В этом была вся она — живущая по принципу «не знаешь, **что сказать**(,) — действуй».*  М. Баконина. Школа двойников (2000)

*Главный принцип: не знаешь, **что делать**(,) — спроси у меня.* В. Васильев. Шуруп (2013)

*Варлам Ратиани в таких случаях говорил: «Не знаешь, **что делать** (,) — ничего не делай, подожди!*  М. Гиголашвили. Чертово колесо (2007)

Comment: Всё правила взыскуешь... 8-( НУЖНА, я сказал.

Comment: Взыскую, но не со всех, нет...

Comment: А что делать?  Вот мне пишут: Розненталю своё не приписывайте: во 2-м случае он говорит только про двоеточие, в 3-м он говорит только про слово "говорит". Про запятую и "думалось" — ваши домыслы.
На этот форум люди приходят именно с вопросом о том, как можно по СТАНДАРТУ. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475052/Подскажите-пожалуйста-корректно-ли-так-оформить-предложение-с-такой-вот-двойно/475054?noredirect=1#comment517446_475054

Comment: "В литературе встречаются разные варианты". Непонятно, где разные варианты – везде стоят запятые в скобках.

Comment: Непонятно. Надо самим знаки выбрать.  А в литературе ответы к решениям. Хотите попробовать? Максим ваш не справился с заданием))  У него все одинаково просто, с интонацией вроде бы давно разобрался, как и со всем остальным, а ответы не сходятся.

Answer (score 0):

По [первому пункту](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176) запятая нужна. Вот пример из справочника:

> *Я отвечал, что меня беспокоят мухи, — и мы оба замолчали* (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть, тире поставлено перед частью предложения, выражающей следствие.

В ваших тоже придаточную часть нужно закрыть:

*Не знаешь, что сказать, — действуй*;

*Не знаешь, что сказать, – так хоть молчать научись*;

*Не знаешь, что делать, — спроси у меня*;

*Не знаешь, что делать, — ничего не делай, подожди!*

Тире стоит между частями БСП, условно-следсдвенные отношения. Союз ЕСЛИ отсутствует, поэтому только тире. Запятыми с двух сторон закрываем придаточное, т. к. следственная часть относится не к придаточному, а тому, что перед придаточным.

Comment: Удивительно! Правило есть, решение тоже,  пример — пожалуйста, а ответы не совпадают. В двух поставлена запятая, а в двух нет. Этот загадочный русский язык...

Comment: @Sharon Ошибка, значит. Запятые в любом случае во всех примерах нужны.

Comment: Класс!  Здесь становится все веселее...  А что, у этих писателей чувства языка не хватило, чтобы до правил дотянуть?

Comment: Это либо ошибка, либо правида другие были. Но по современным правилам запятая нужна.

Comment: Да это же современная литература, не Толстой и не Достоевский.  Наверное, все же чувство языка.  Кстати интонация там разная, приглядитесь. У нас при значении следствия тон повышается или понижается?

Comment: Вас очень сложно переубедить. Думайте как хотите, но своë мнение я высказал, пример привел и всë объяснил. Больше мне добавить нечего.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, но оно не совпадет с текстом. Я не просто думаю, мне надо решить задачу и правильно обосновать решение. Это можно проверить по Нацкорпусу.  Есть отношения взаимообусловленные: там нужен сильный знак. А есть отношения следственные, там и тире достаточно. И вот где какие? Интонация разная.